# Почему мотают на ус?

Tags: фразеология

Есть поговорка «мотать на ус» в значении «принять к сведению и запомнить». Например:

> Давай, дружище, мотай на ус: вот этим концом на чёрта направлять надо, а вот сюда грудью упираться. И вообще, в одиночку на чёрта ходить не надо, заруби себе это на носу!

Но ведь в ее основе явно лежит какое-то конкретное действие и переносный смысл она получила уже потом. Интересно было бы узнать, кто и что мотал на ус и почему это означает не столько запоминание каких-то обстоятельств, сколько именно их учет и прием к сведению? Откуда пошла эта поговорка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение, с одной стороны, связано с символикой усов как атрибута мужской зрелости и опыта, с другой — с древней системой запоминания — завязыванием узелков «на память». Чем длиннее ус, тем больше можно «намотать» жизненного опыта — такова шутливая основа выражения.